# Is it possible to lose the TextMate Markdown Preview header?

Tags: macos, textmate, user-interface

Is it possible to remove the header in TextMate's Markdown Preview mode, or make it smaller?

It takes quite a bit of screen space.

[image: TextMate markdown preview pane screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/themes/bright/style.css`:

```
#tm_webpreview_header { display: none; }
#tm_webpreview_content { margin: 0 !important; }
```

[image]

Comment: yup, there's a CSS for that :) thanks, I was just discovering that by myself / posting the answer. Silly me.